# Batching instead of looping gives incorrect result

Tags: python, batch-processing, tensor, torch

I have the following function

```
def random_sample(feature, pool_idx):
    """
    :param feature: [B, N, d] input features matrix
    :param pool_idx: [B, N', max_num] N' < N, N' is the selected position after pooling
    :return: pool_features = [B, N', d] pooled features matrix
    """
    if len(feature.size()) > 3: # bs*c*p*1
        feature = feature.squeeze(dim=3)  # batch*channel*npoints
    num_neigh = pool_idx.shape[-1]
    d = feature.shape[1]
    batch_size = pool_idx.shape[0]
    pool_idx = pool_idx.reshape(batch_size, -1)  # batch*(npoints,nsamples)
    pool_features = torch.gather(
        feature, 2, pool_idx.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, feature.shape[1], 1)
    ).contiguous()
    pool_features = pool_features.reshape(batch_size, d, -1, num_neigh)
    pool_features = pool_features.max(dim=3, keepdim=True)[0]  # batch*channel*npoints*1
    return pool_features
```

I call it with `r2p_emb = random_sample(rgb_emb0_tmp,inputs['r2p_ds_nei_idx0'])`
Where `rgb_emb0_tmp` is of size `(batch, channel, pts, 1)`
and `inputs['r2p_ds_nei_idx0']` is of size `(batch, sample_pts, neighbors)`
and `r2p_emb` will be of size `(batch, channel, sample_pts, 1)`

Now my input changes to
`rgb_emb0_tmp` is of size `(batch, views, channel, pts, 1)` and
`inputs['r2p_ds_nei_idx0']` is of size `(batch, views, sample_pts, neighbors)`
but I want that each view is processed independently so I can concatenate in the end to get
`r2p_emb` of shape `(batch, channel, views * sample_pts, 1)`

```
r2p_emb = torch.cat([random_sample(rgb_emb0_tmp[:,i,:,:],inputs['r2p_ds_nei_idx0'][:,i,:,:]) for i in range(views)],dim=2)
```

To vectorize this in my mind I just have to reshape `rgb_emb0_tmp` to shape `(batch * views, channel, pts, 1)` and `inputs['r2p_ds_nei_idx0']` to shape `(batch * views, sample_pts, neighbors)` and then finally reshape to shape `r2p_emb` of shape `(batch, channel, views * sample_pts, 1)`

This is my thought process. But somehow, somewhere this solutions produces two different end results, I checked it with `abs(r2p_emb_loop-r2p_emb_vec).max()`
which is greater than 0. But it only seems to be the order of the values because the min, mean and max of both tensors is identical.

So where is my solution/my thought process wrong?

Comment: I think the problem might be how torch.view() and torch.reshape() works. What I want (I think) is for example: tensor of shape (bs, views, pts) bs = 2 views =3 pts = 10 to (bs*views,pts). I want ((bs1view1,bs1view2,bs1view3,   bs2view1,bs2view2,bs2view3),pts) but it gives me  ((bs1view1,bs2view1,   bs1view2,bs2view2,    bs1view3,bs2view3),pts).

Does this make sense? I think that might be the problem